# About the integral bounds of Jacobian

Tags: multiple-integral, jacobian

Given D={(x,y)|x⩾0,y⩾0,x+y⩽1}, find the value of $\iint _{D} e^{x+y} dxdy$

Method 1:
\begin{array}{l}
\iint _{D} e^{x+y} dxdy=\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1-y} e^{x+y} dxdy\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =\int _{0}^{1} e^{y}\left( e^{1-y} -1\right) dy\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ =1
\end{array}

Then I tried to solve this question by Jacobian

\begin{array}{l}
Let\ u=x+y,\ v=x,\ 0\leqslant v\leqslant u\leqslant 1\\
\begin{cases}
x=v\\
y=u-v
\end{cases}\\
J=\begin{vmatrix}
x_{u} & y_{u}\\
x_{v} & y_{v}
\end{vmatrix} =\begin{vmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1 & -1
\end{vmatrix} =-1
\end{array}

The different results that came out from the different integral bounds confused me.
\begin{cases}
\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{u} e^{u} |J|dvdu=1\\
\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1} e^{u} |J|dvdu=e-1
\end{cases}

The integral bounds of Jacobian should be constants, but the result isn't the same as the one in method 1.
And I tried to change the integral bounds from $\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1} dvdu$ to $\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{u} dvdu$. The results are the same, but the integral bounds of Jacobian aren't like that.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bounds have not Jacobian, but integration area. When you fixed area, then result will be unambiguous.

Comment: @zkutch Thanks for your hint. So, for this question, the correct integral bound should be $\int _{0}^{1}\int _{0}^{1} dvdu\ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds are not required to be constants.  They are just preferred to be nice to work with.

$$\begin{align}\iint_D \mathrm e^{x+y}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y&=\iint_{0\leqslant x\leqslant x+y\leqslant 1}\mathrm e^{x+y}\,\mathrm d x\,\mathrm d y\\&= \iint_{0\leq v\leqslant u\leqslant 1} \mathrm e^u\,\lVert\mathbf J_{v,u}^{v,u-v}\rVert\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u\\&=\int_0^1\mathrm e^u\int_0^\color{crimson}u 1\,\mathrm d v\,\mathrm d u\\&=1\end{align}$$